# Why focus event doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
function removeWrongClass(el){
  el.removeClass('wrong');
}

$(".ask_q_title_input").on('focus', removeWrongClass($(this)));
```

```css
.wrong{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="ask_q_title_input wrong" type="text" />
```

Expected behavior is removing that *red* background color *(which is because of `.wrong` class)* from the input when you focus on the input. But it doesn't happen. What's wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: because it is working correctly, you just didn't give it a function to execute.

Comment: @KevinB What? I call `removeWrongClass($(this)` ..

Comment: exactly, you *called* it. you didn't pass it.

Comment: @KevinB So? if I call it, then why `el.removeClass('wrong');` doesn't execute?

Comment: because it does execute. Look at your console. add a console.log to it.

Comment: You call it immediately, not when the element gets focus. `.on()` needs to be passed a function, you're passing it the return value of a function call.

Comment: Not sure why we're beating around the bush with cryptic hints here, but the bottom line is that if you're trying to *pass* a function, it cannot include parameters. The `focus` event wants a function, but you're not giving it a function - by including parameters, you're passing the **result** of a function. You'd be best off using an anonymous function, like `.on("focus", function() { removeWrongClass($(this)) });`

Comment: @Santi In reality, that function isn't just containing one line. And I need to call it for other cases.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest Santi's solution. Instead, you can do `.on('focus', removeWrongClass);` and then instead of having `removeWrongClass(el)` you just have `removeWrongClass()` and instead of using `el` you use `$(this)` as you would regularly.

Comment: @stack No, because `el` isn't an element when you call it. the way you are.

Comment: What if he wants to manually call the function with a different element, other than `$(this)`?

Comment: @Santi `theFunction.call(whateverthisshoudlbe)`

Comment: @stack I mean, despite whether its the best practice, I gave you a 100% working & re-usable answer in the comments above. Your response for why my comment *wouldn't* work doesn't exactly make sense to me. `$("element").on("focus", function() { //Put 1,000 lines of code here }):`

Comment: @stack https://jsfiddle.net/tfvhtxwh/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you are calling the function, instead of passing it as the function to run.

```js
function removeWrongClass(){
  $(this).removeClass('wrong');
}

function toggleWrongClass(){
  $(this).toggleClass('wrong');
}

$(".ask_q_title_input").on('focus', removeWrongClass);

$(".ask_q_title_input_toggle").on('focus focusout', toggleWrongClass);
```

```css
.wrong{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Turn off wrong on focus - <input class="ask_q_title_input wrong" type="text" /><br/>
Toggle wrong on focus in and out - <input class="ask_q_title_input_toggle wrong" type="text" />
```

If you would like to use `removeWrongClass` on another element you can call it as follows -

```
removeWrongClass.call(elementYouWantAsThis)
```

Comment: In this case, I cannot pass a parameter. Right?! Because sometimes I need to affect on other element.

Comment: @stack what other element would you need to change? Is it in relation to the input, because if so you can use dom traversal to change the other element as well.